# How to use react-router with React.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a asp.net project with react and want to use react-router. On its [git repo](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/01-setting-up) the setup is only explained for Node.js. I found the `TypeScript` packages of **NuGet** but after installing them, I cannot build my project anymore due to compilation errors.

Does anyone have experience with installing react-router for asp.net projects?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can't run `JavaScript` Code in server-sided `.net` Applications.

Comment: Doesn't react-router run on the client? Just like react itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did to build our application in React. We created our whole application in React in Visual Studio Code with Redux and React-Router. Webpack is used to build all the files. Once whole application is completed, we build the js (transpiled and minified) and added a script tag pointing to that url of the bundle js into our web application page (specifically .aspx page).

Now issues you might face with react-router, if you have hosted it inside a directory of your existing project. For e.g. inside root - you have folder named myapp. If that is the case - you need to make changes to your Routes in your react app to have a base name.

I tried React.NET but after doing it this way - I really liked this approach as you can separately build the whole application with all the awesome tools you have in client side ecosystem - for instance - hot reloading

Hope it helps.

Comment: what about SEO and other benefits of using react.net?

Comment: For SEO - you need to do some processing for handling different routes. We have excluded that part for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used React.NET, but what you can do is create a separate project, outside of your ASP.NET project. Use webpack for bundling and other purposes. Build your react project, which generates static assets (main.js, chunks, css files and images/sprites). Add these generated files in your ASP.NET project directly and set `index.html` as Start Page.

We have built our React project on top of [this boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate). It uses industry-grade ways of optimization, uglification, minification, bundling and what not! Good luck!